# Conditional replace of DataFrame column content based on a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Data frame and a list, and I am trying to update the columns of the Data frame basis the list.

```
df= pd.DataFrame()
df['ID']=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
df['Quantity']=[100,10,20,30,40,50]
zero_list=[2,3]
```

I want to replace the 'Quantity'to zero, for the ID`s mentioned in the zero list.

One way of doing it is to convert the list to tuple and using np.where I want to look at an alternate way of doing it, as the conversion from list to tuple still gives be hashable error.

The following table is derived from a for loop:

```
                                   id     Quantity
0                                  []         0
1                                  []         0
2                                  []         0
3                                  []         0
4                                  []         0
5                                  []         0
6                                  []         0
7                                  []         0
8                                  []         0
9                                  []         0
10                                 []         0
11                                 []         0
12                                 []         0
13                                 []         0
14                                 []         0
15              [20529, 25000, 22123]         0
16                                 []         0
```

and I am creating the zero list from row 15.

Comment: Un-stacking the list could be a probable way to approach it!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df.loc[df['ID'].isin(zero_list), 'Quantity']=0
```

`df['ID'].isin(zero_list)` created a mask just like `np.where`

Comment: LOL, hahaha, hihi

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you need:

```
df.loc[df['ID'].isin(zero_list),'Quantity']=0
```

So use `loc` to get the values in `ID` column that are in `zero_list`, then make `Quantity` column zero,

or use `eval`, basically same thing:

```
df.loc[df.eval('ID in @zero_list'),'Quantity']=0
```